# Using jQuery to add components to a glTF file in A-Frame?

Tags: animation, aframe, setattribute, gltf

I have [an A-Frame scene](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/poc-gltf-anim-triggering) with three gltf models in it.

I am trying to programmatically trigger animations and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Probably something very obvious, I'll admit. But after hours of researching and fiddling, there must be something very basic that isn't clicking with me.

Be nice - my js isn't exactly beautiful. It's a huge work in progress.

Check out the Glitch Project for more context, but this is probably a problem because I'm using jQuery to store the entity (see below). Right? Is that why? If so, what do I do about it?

```
function triggerClip(model, clipToPlay, clipDirection) {
  model.setAttribute('animation-mixer', {
    clip: clipToPlay,
    timeScale: clipDirection
  });
}
```

EDIT: After making the changes [suggested by Diego](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53640193/825108), the animations played but I was still getting warnings about timeScale not being recognized. I had to update the version of A-Frame extras to get it working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery wraps native DOM elements in its own structure. You have to do the following to access it:

```
 model[0].setAttribute('animation-mixer', {
    clip: 'step' + clipToPlay,
    timeScale: clipDirection
  });
```

Comment: This will add the attribute to the model, but the values aren't being set at all.

Comment: I figured another thing out. I was using an outdated version of a-frame extras! D'oh. This resolved my issue with the timeScale not being understood by the browser.